# How to turn on/off leds by terminal?

Tags: keyboard, terminal, led, linux-terminal

I would like turn on/turn off some of my leds running a command on linux.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I tried

```
xset led named "Scroll Lock"
xset led named "Num Lock"
xset led 2             (this is the number of Scroll Lock as `xset q` says)
xset led 1
```

but nothing works.

Tried

```
setleds +num
setleds +scroll
```

but I got a error message saying `Error reading the current settings of flags. Maybe you're not on the console?` (I was in a terminal).

So, how can I perform this?

Answer (score 11):

xdotool key Num_Lock

Is the an answer (the easiest you're likely to find); inverting the state, it also provides a path to search (xinput and modifying a slave keyboard state) if you really just want to set an led status.

I too ran across my Num Lock keyboard LED and X11 state differing recently (happens with remote desktops, games, etc)

This reference explains what's going on, and almost has the complete solution (but it has a case-typo, you need Num_Lock not Num_lock).

http://blog.ssokolow.com/archives/2013/04/18/how-to-invert-your-x11-numlock-led/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Best solution I've ever seen. Thank you! The lights are so annoying!

Comment: Note that `xdotool key Num_Lock` is not as innocent as turning a LED on or off; It is the equivalent of actually pressing the key!

Answer (score 7):

To turn Scroll Lock led on run:

```
xset -led 2 led on
```

To turn it off run:

```
xset -led 2 led off
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also solution without any extra software.
Just use:

```
echo "1" > /sys/class/leds/input20::scrolllock/brightness
#Or
echo "1" > /sys/class/leds/input20::/brightness
```

as root.

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login, and then try `setleds`.

Comment: Interesting. `setleds` (not `xset`) worked for me now too. Looks like we need set a `display`. I tried several things but nothing worked. But, looks we're almost.

Comment: This isnt the final answer to me, because I need this working on the gui display, not at the console display.

Answer (score 0):

Install xf86-input-keyboard if you don't have it.

Set `kbd_mode -u`

Make sure you don't have multiple instances of the KB (check what XINPUT: reports).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179286/59955), if your screen is on TTY1, but you try to control the LEDs from somewhere else (such as an SSH session), you can use `setleds` in the following way:

```
setleds -L +num +caps +scroll < /dev/tty1
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the command:

```
numlockx on
```

or

```
numlockx off
```

to change the state.

Comment: This is rather brief: some more detail would be helpful. For example, in what circumstances does this command work?

Comment: It does exactly what it sounds like.